# Android Auto boot/connected receiver

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm currently developing app for Android Auto (Android for cars). I need to know when user connected phone to car. Is there any action like Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, which I can observe in my application code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`CarConnection` API](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#car-connection) from the Android for Cars App Library. Note that, unlike most other APIs in the library, you just need a `Context` and not a [`CarContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/CarContext) to call this API, so it can be used outside of a [`CarAppService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/CarAppService).